# Compare wildcard string inside bash awk command

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Is there a way to compare a substring with wildcard in bash inside “awk” command like this

`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="redis-*") print $(i+1)}' /etc/redis/sentinel.conf | head -1`

I want the command to look for any string  that starts with “redis-” e.g., redis-pers, redis-test, redis-session etc from the sentinel.conf file.

I do not want to grep the string (e.g., redis-test), but the string that following the wildcard.
So if the sentinel.conf file has a line like tis
`sentinel known-slave redis-test 192.168.1.100 6379`
, i want to return  192.168.1.100

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with bash or shell.

Comment: This is a bash command, and i just want help on how this can be accomplished

Comment: Awk is not a bash command, it's a programming language. `if ($i~/^redis-/)` [This](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Comparison-Operators.html) is a start.

Comment: I see. Now that that is cleared, how can i achieve what i have presented?

Comment: You can see all bash commands by typing `help`.

Comment: [edit] your question to contain the missing parts of the [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output if you'd like help. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk doesn't have the glob (wildcard) syntax you're looking for, but you can convert your pattern to a *regular expression* and match that using the `~` operator:

```
if ($i ~ /^redis-/)
```

Regular expressions are more capable than shell globs - any glob pattern can be expressed as a regexp (but not vice versa).

Comment: If you are using Awk anyway, you might as well get rid of the `head`.  `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^redis-/) print $(i+1); exit}' /etc/redis/sentinel.conf`

Comment: `Awk doesn't have wildcards` is a bit misleading. Regexps have `.` which is a wildcard as it matches any character, and then of course you can add `?`, `*`, or `+` to match repetitions of any character.

Comment: Thanks @Ed; it's more accurate to say that regular expressions have a different syntax to shell globs.  I've updated accordingly.